# The Euler constant $e$

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any geometric way to characterize $e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159707/is-there-any-geometric-way-to-characterize-e)

We know that the length of perimeter  of a circle of unit diameter  is $\pi$ ; is there a similar  geometric interpretation of $e$ , without invoking complex numbers, in terms of lenth ( and not area )?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159707/is-there-any-geometric-way-to-characterize-e/159711#159711

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan:- Ah! I get it , it's still an open problem.

Comment: geometric form of e https://geomathry.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

Do a step of length $1$, then a step of half the previous one, then one third the previous one, then one forth the previous one,...

How far do you get?

Comment: That's quite a good way of converting the definition of e into a  geometrical construction , but the process does not end after a finite terms.

Comment: ... which was not requested.

Comment: Oh , sorry for not clarifying that , but however it does not matter cause the question is closed now.