# $\pi$ from the unit circle, $\sqrt 2$ from the unit square but what about $e$?

Tags: geometry, intuition, exponential-function, visualization, constants

If one wants to introduce $\pi$ to a not mathematically savvy person, the unit circle would be a good choice. The unit square would be the way to go for $\sqrt 2$. But what about $e$? I've reviewed the alternative characterizations on wikipedia and they all involve limiting processes in one form or another. So I was wondering: Is there a visual, easy-to-grasp way to present $e$? (Even if the presentation wouldn't be mathematically equivalent to the usual ones.)

Comment: You could demonstrate that $e^x$ is invariant under derivation? Is that too mathematical?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern, in comparison to the circle and square it's somewhat mathematical. I was looking for something more tangible.

Comment: The most "geometric" is that the area under the curve $(x,1/x)$ with $x\in[1,e)$ is $1$. That doesn't seem nearly as intuitive, however - it is not a length or area.  $e$ comes up a lot as a limit - for example, the derangement problem, or when dealing with compound interest.

Comment: At heart I think this is the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159707/is-there-any-geometric-way-to-characterize-e which has been asked here a few times over.

Comment: @ErickWong: you're right. I had a strong feeling that it must have been asked here before yet couldn't find anything. Thanks for the link.

Comment: $e$ appears naturally in [hyperbolic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry).

Comment: $\sinh 1 + \cosh 1$.

Comment: I think this question is rescuable as an independent question; the other question specifically asks for _geometric_ ways of constructing $e$, whereas this question asks for intuitive ways of describing $e$ to a layperson, which certainly don't need to be geometric.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The number $e$ is the number such that the area enclosed by the region bounded by $x=1$ on the left-hand side, the $X$ axis from below, $y=1/x$ from above and $x=e$ on the right-hand side is $1$. Hence, $e$ can be defined as the length (you need to add $1$, since you measure the length from $1$) you need to move along $X$ axis such that the area of the above enclosed figure is $1$.

[image]

Comment: *I am a kid, I don't understand areas or integral*. Now?

Comment: You don't need integrals to understand area.

Comment: Agreed..Was being sarcastic(+1)

Comment: @Inceptio. If you don't understand area, it's liquely you won't understand $pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ either.

Comment: @arbautjc: How will you bring in $\pi$ to a kid? With a pictorial representation. He/she understands the concept of $\pi$, and anyway, $e$ has not fallen from heaven, it can be understood even by a small kid if there existed a very *elementary proof* for this.

Comment: @Inceptio The number $\pi$ is defined as the circumference of a circle with unit diameter. Similarly, $e$ is defined as the length you need to move along $X$ axis such that the area of the above enclosed figure is $1$.

Comment: @Viv: I get it. I do.

Comment: What did you use to graph this?

Comment: @ZettaSuro The graph was made in GeoGebra on ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

A different take on the 'classical' limit that I think is my favorite way of thinking about $e$ recreationally (and a remarkably useful approximation for many games): "I take a six-sided die and roll it six times.  What are the odds I never roll '1' in those six rolls?  Okay, now I take a twenty-sided die and roll it twenty times.  What are the odds I never roll '1' in those 20 rolls?"  The latter value, of course, is $\left(\dfrac{19}{20}\right)^{20} = \left(1-\dfrac{1}{20}\right)^{20}\approx e^{-1}\approx .37$; in fact, it's within a 3% relative approximation.

This is a nice way of showing the limiting process in action 'in reality', especially for any gamers, and the way that the result (power-law) scales with number of rolls is an excellent back-of-the-envelope estimate for figuring probabilities on the fly; I can know that if I roll that d20 ten times, I've got roughly a $\sqrt{.36}\approx 60\%$ chance of not hitting a 20, or equivalently a $40\%$ chance of getting one.  (Or, to pick a different example, I can know that with 3 Plains left in my Magic sealed deck's 30-card library, my odds of drawing one in the next ten turns are only about 2/3rds.)

Comment: Similarly, if a lazy coat room attendant for a large event hands back coats randomly, what is the approximate probability that nobody gets their own coat back?  (The `hat' variant is more commonly told but seems a bit contrived.)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Even though I wouldn't try to use this way to explain $e$ to a person who doesn't understand limiting process (the odds are that he doesn't understand probability either, since it's more advanced in my opinion). Yet I highly enjoyed the answer myself. Do you have a nice example of a word problem converging to $e$ instead of $e^{-1}$?

Answer (score 8):

It's the only number where this happens:

[image]

Comment: What just happened?

Answer (score 6):

The notion of [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods), which is introduced by Kontsevich and Zagier, would partially give a negative answer to your question. According to this article, it is now known whether $e$ is a period or not, though it is conjecturedly not a peroid. In particular, $e$ seems not to arise as an area or a length of a geometric figure defined by an algebraic equation.

This may imply that any description involving $e$ would eventually require some extent of advanced calculus.

We may circumvent this problem by arguing that the concept of $e$ arises rather naturally by considering some real-world problems. For example, we can think of compound interest:

Given an annual interest $100r$% with compounding period $1/n$ year, the relative value at the end of a year is

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{n}, $$

which converges to $e^{r}$ as $n \to \infty$ (that is, the period of interest goes to zero).

Here is another, though odd, characterization of $e$:

Suppose that a drunk man starts at $x = 0$ at time $t = 0$, and then at each second he walks to the right with a step size randomly and evenly between $0$ and $1$. That is, if $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables having a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, then the position of the drunk man at time $t = n$ is $x = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Let $T$ be the time when his position first exceeds the point $x = 1$. Then the mean of $T$ is exactly $e$.

Answer (score 3):

> $$e\approx 2.71828182846$$

Consider the equation:

$$f(n)=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$

As $n$ gets larger and larger, notice what the result approaches.

$$f(1)=2$$
$$f(2)=2.25$$
$$f(3)\approx2.3703703$$
$$...$$
$$f(100)\approx2.7048138$$
$$...$$

Comment: Have you read the question?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Why yes, I did read the question I answered.

Comment: What's visual and easy-to-grasp in this answer?

Answer (score 2):

This one is not visual or graphical, but may be easiest to understand for a non-mathematician.

Suppose you have $\$1000$ and you want to put it in a bank account. You have picked a bank that, besides giving you an absurd interest over your money, gives you a choice between several interest schemes:

1. An annual interest of $100\%$.
2. An interest of $50\%$, but then twice a year.
3. A quarterly interest of $25\%$.
4. A monthly interest of $8.33\%$.
5. ...
6. A daily interest of $0.27397\ldots\%$
7. ...

As you may have picked up, the interest is $1/k$, where $k$ is the number of times a year you get that interest. Of course, the interest is computed over the *current* amount of money in your bank account, including previous interest.

So which scheme would you choose? And how much money would you have after $1$ year?