# Is $e$ (Euler's number) involved in some geometric figure in any way?

Tags: geometry, constants

Let's take some popular numbers in math: $\pi$, $e$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\phi$. The number $\pi$ is the ratio between the circumference and the diameter of a circle; $\sqrt{2}$ is the length of a diagonal of a unit square, $\phi$ is the length of a diagonal of a regular unit pentagon. It seems like $e$ is not a part of any reasonably familiar geometric shape.

Is this really so? By 'familiar geometric figure' I mean a geometric figure $F$ that hasn't been artificially constructed so that $e$ is somehow a part of it. By 'part' here I mean the ratio of something in $F$ and something else in $F$, the length of something in $F$, the area of $F$, maybe its perimeter, etc.

Comment: One example could be that it's the $x$ such that $\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=1$. But I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Seems like an artificial geometric figure to me. It doesn't arise "naturally" in math if you forget its connection to $e$.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean by an "artificial geometric figure"; the area under the graph could be constructed outside of an $(x,y)$ plane just as a circle or square could be.

Comment: Well, guys... you know what I mean. I've tried as much as I could to convey my thoughts.

Comment: Actually, your meaning still isn't entirely clear to me. Do you just want regular shapes? I don't see why the area under a graph is any more artificial than a circle.

Comment: I want the geometric figure to be "closer" to "classic geometry" rather than to calculus. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well I think therein lies your problem: $e$ wasn't known until calculus so it's unlikely to appear without it.

Comment: @EulCan I think you are completely right here. Turns out the question was dumb :(

Comment: I wouldn't say that calculating the area of a piece of hyperbola is not sufficiently related to classic geometry. In this sense $\pi$ is related to the area of the possitive conic (circle and ellipse) and $e$ to the area of the negative one (hyperbola).

Comment: another thread [Is there any geometric way to characterize e
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159707/is-there-any-geometric-way-to-characterize-e)

Answer (score 4):

It may be a stretch, but a claim can be made that the catenary is a mesmerizing geometrical object that is all about the Euler constant.

Given by its expression:

$$f(x) =  \cosh(x ) = \frac 1 2 \left(e^{x} + e^{-x}\right),$$

it is the average of exponential growth and decay:

[image]

And although this implies that calculus is never left behind, it also results in a perfect architectural and engineering structure (with a minus in front): the catenary arc.

[image: Casa Milà, Antoni Gaudí]

Casa Milà, Antoni Gaudí

The equation of a catenary can be derived with a contrained (by the length of the chain) [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) assuming uniform physical properties.

It is not surprising that the catenary arc is described as ["an arch of uniform density and thickness, supporting only its own weight, the catenary is the ideal curve,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary_arch#:%7E:text=For%20an%20arch%20of%20uniform,pressing%20along%20the%20arch%27s%20curve.) when it is (aside from constants) the only function to preserve the ratio between the arc length of any interval and the area subtended:

[image]

And although this may sound like it is steering off topic, it is a beautiful counterpoint to $e^x$ being its own integral (up to a constant). Further, this ratio between area under the curve and arc length corresponds to the scaling parameter $a$ in the general equation of the catenary $a \cosh(x/a),$ and can be interpreted as the interest rate in the continuous compounding formula $e^{x/a}.$ In a way a perfect arch is the physical picture of continuously compounded interest.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the graph of the funcion $f(x) = a^x$, with $a > 0$. Well, $f(0) = 1$ in any way, but we want more. Looking at the tangent line to the graph at the point $(0,1)$, what is the base $a$ such that the inclination of the line is $1$? This happens just when $a = e = 2,718281828459045\ldots$. Analytically, this translates as $f'(x) = a^x \ln a $, and $f'(0) = 1$, since $\ln e = 1 $. Hope this helps.