# Estimating the value of $e$ using a random function

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, analysis, statistics

I encountered the question which asks you to estimate the value of $\pi$ by using a function which generates a random real number in $[0,1]$ (and it's uniformly distributed). The way is to use the function twice to get a real pair which we can view it as a point on the Euclidean plane, then use the idea of the Monte Carlo method. I wonder if we can also use this function to estimate $e$, however, I cannot find any geometrical interpretation of the number, or can this problem be solved in other ways?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159707/is-there-any-geometric-way-to-characterize-e)

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193990/approximate-e-using-monte-carlo-simulation

Answer (score 19):

Generate $N$ random permutations (possibly with [Knuth's shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

Then count how many of them are [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement): $N_D$.

Then $$\frac N{N_D}\simeq e$$

Comment: A beautiful solution!

Comment: But it only holds when N is sufficiently large, computing N! would be painful…

Comment: @JWang No, the true ratio converges quickly to $1/e$ as $k$ grows ($k$ being the permutation length). However, convergence of the monte carlo approximation is much slower. For permutations on $k=10$ elements, with $N=10^8$ samples, I get $N/N_D\simeq2.718006253262627$. Not too bad. And whatever the permutation length, you need many samples anyway: with only one, even though the probability is close to $1/e$, there are only two possible values for $N_D/N$: $0$ or $1$.

Comment: A quick and dirty coding exercise provides `e = 2.718 +-0.036` with about a 1000 samples of about 1000 elements each.  
https://pastebin.com/gAEXhdWf

Comment: If you're taking fewer than $k!$ samples, the sample size is the majority of your error: with $N$ samples, your error is on the order of $\pm \frac1{\sqrt N}$, whereas the true fraction of derangements is within $\frac1{k!}$ of $\frac1e$. If, on the other hand, you're taking $k!$ or more samples, you should just go ahead and count all the derangements, instead of sampling them randomly :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov True. :)

Answer (score 11):

Draw $X_i \sim \text{Unif}(1,3)$ and $Y_i \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$. Reject the samples where $Y_i > 1/X_i$. Sort the accepted $X_i$ values and take the $(N/2)$th.

This relies on the observation that $\int_1^e dx/x = 1$. So we do rejection sampling in the rectangle $[1,3] \times [0,1]$ to get points under the $1/x$ curve. By taking the $(N/2)$th smallest value we are finding the point where we have $1/2$ of the original points, that is, area $1$ (observing that the original rectangle has area $2$).

Here is the simulation with $N=10000$ points. The rejected points are in cyan. From the accepted points, the leftmost $N/2=5000$ are in black and the rest are in blue.

[image: Monte Carlo estimation of e]

Comment: Nice! Here is a way to do this with way fewer rejections. Just generate $n$ iid points uniformly between $1$ and $3$, sort them so $1<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n<3$, then use them as a mesh to approximate $\int_1^{x_i} dx/x$ with the midpoint rule. Keep increasing $i$ until the first time the approximate integral exceeds $1$. Then $e\approx x_i$.

Comment: Mike, your solution is infinitely better than mine in terms of efficiency! I was striving to emulate the original "points in the disk for $\pi$" spirit as closely as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Flip a biased coin $K$ times which has probability of heads $\frac{1}{K}$; let $X_1$ denotes the number of heads that show up. Repeating this process $N$ times gives you $N$ counts of heads $X_1,...,X_N$. Then $$\frac{N}{\Big|\big\{1 \leq i \leq N:X_i=1\big\}\Big|}\approx e$$ when $N$ and $K$ are large.

Answer (score 3):

Pick $N$ random integers $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ uniformly and independently in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, and then count the number $N_d$ of *distinct* integers in this list, or equivalently, let

$$ N_d = \#\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N\}. $$

Then for large $N$,

$$ \frac{N}{N-N_d} \approx e. $$

(That is, the size of the random set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}$ is approximately $(1-e^{-1})N$.)

Answer (score 2):

The minimum number of Uniform(0,1) random variables required in order for their sum to exceed $1$ is on average (exactly) $e$. More generally, if $0 < a \le 1$ then the minimum number of Uniform(0,1) variables required in order to exceed $a$ is $e^a$.

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Uniform(0,1) random variables, and let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

As a first step, we claim $$P(S_n \le a) =\frac{a^n}{n!} \tag{*}$$
for $0 < a \le 1$ and $n \ge 0$.  Proof by induction on $n$: The case $n=0$ is trivial.  Suppose that $(*)$ holds from some $n$.  Then
$$P(S_{n+1} \le a) = \int_0^a \frac{(a-x)^n}{n!} \;dx = \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \frac{a^{n+1}}{n} = \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
and the proof is complete.

Now define $m(a)$ to be the least value of $n$ such that $S_n > a$.  We have $m(a) > n$ exactly when $S_n \le a$, so
$$E(m(a)) = \sum_{n \ge 0} P(m(a) > n) = \sum_{n \ge 0} P(S_n \le a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} = e^a$$

Answer (score 2):

Choose a sequence of random numbers from $[0,1]$, stopping when the $n$-th choice exceeds the $(n-1)$-th choice. Repeat, averaging the $(n-1)$-th values. This average will approach $3-e$.

Comment: Nice! However, could it be that this approximates $e - 2$ rather than $3 - e$?

Comment: no, I am pretty sure it is 3-e. How did you get e-2?

Comment: I just tried it out! Note that the average will certainly be more than $1/2$, since that is the expected value of the first draw, and the generated value will always be at least equal to the first draw.

Comment: I'll paste by program (in Python3), so that you can see if I misunderstood your algorithm:

Comment: from random import random
    
    def s():
        a = random()
        b = random()
        while b > a:
            a = b
            b = random()
        return a
    
    
    N = 1000000; print(2 + sum(s() for i in range(N))/ N)

Comment: This generates a value really close to $e$. Apologies for the layout, apparently you cannot write code in a comment

Comment: The average will be *less* than .5, as that will be the expected value from terminations on second choice; remember we are constructing a *decreasing* sequence.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't read it carefully, I was constructing an *increasing* sequence! So the average of your samples $s$ is the same as the average of my samples $1 - s$

Answer (score 1):

Pick $n$ numbers uniformly in $[0,1]$.  Let $X_n$ be the value $x$ that you picked, for which $x^x$ takes the smallest value.  Then as $n\to\infty$ we have $\mathbb{E}X_n\to \frac 1e$.

Proof: First note that $x^x$ has a minima at $x=\frac1e$. Also note that both branches of the inverse function to $x^x, x\in[0,1]$ are continuous. For $\epsilon>0$ pick $\delta>0$ such that $x^x<\left(\frac1e\right)^\frac1e+\delta\implies |x-\frac1e|<\epsilon$.  For sufficiently large $n$, the probability that none of the numbers sampled satisfies $x^x<\left(\frac1e\right)^\frac1e+\delta$ is less than $\epsilon$ and if one of the numbers sampled does satisfy this then $X_n$ will too, so $|X_n-\frac1e|<\epsilon$.  Thus $$(\frac1e-\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)<\mathbb{E}X_n\leq (\frac1e+\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)+\epsilon.$$

---

Ordering the $x^x$ reduces to integer arithmetic:

To order the $x^x, y^y$ one can sandwich them between rationals: $$\frac{a_x}{b_x}\leq x\leq\frac{c_x}{d_x},\qquad   \frac{a_y}{b_y}\leq y\leq\frac{c_y}{d_y},\qquad a_x,b_x,c_x,d_x\in \mathbb{N},$$
so that $$f(\frac{a_x}{b_x}),f(\frac{c_x}{d_x})\leq f(\frac{a_y}{b_y}),f(\frac{c_y}{d_y}) \qquad {\rm or}\quad f(\frac{a_x}{b_x}),f(\frac{c_x}{d_x})\geq f(\frac{a_y}{b_y}),f(\frac{c_y}{d_y}), 
$$
where $f(x)=x^x$.

To compare $f(\frac{u}{v})$ and $f(\frac{z}{w})$ with $u,v,w,z\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, note that $$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{\frac{u}{v}}\leq \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^{\frac{z}{w}}\iff
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{{u}{w}}\leq \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^{{z}{v}}\iff
u^{uw}w^{zv}\leq z^{zv}v^{uw}.$$

---