# Please help I'm in grade 9 and excellent at maths but I keep asking why does it work

Tags: proof-explanation

Please help, i'm in grade 9 and get exellent maths grades and everyone regard me smart but I keep asking myself why does this work and it gets really bothering
Example when we studyed system of equations I start ask why does the substition method works, when we substitue the value will that make the equation (1) work, why does solving equation works.Then I start ask my self why do basic properties work why a/b * c=ac/b? and this is really confusing me please help what should I do I love mathsss
Thanks everyone for answering I will tell you how I see for now why substitution (wich sometime is not convincing for me and I start looking for more details) so is this convincing:
Consider the system:
ax+by=c (1)
a'x+b'x=c' (2)
For x to be a solution of equation (1) it has to respect the relation
x=(c-by)/a
we substitute this value of x into the second equation for it to to be solution of both equation, we find y and then we find is this enough proof or I have to think deeper?

Comment: Where is the equation (1)?

Comment: I'm speaking generally

Comment: I want to show that I really ask the questio WHY and it gets me really confused

Comment: Hi there Selim. It's easier for the people who post answers here to help you if you can make your questions clear. You seem to have two questions here, one about why substitution works and one about fractions. In future, try to make the title and the content of your post clearly about the question, rather than saying many times that you are confused.

Comment: its not only about that , I can do every maths problem about subsitution and everything the problem is that I ask too many questions , I just gave substituion and fraction as an example

Comment: It still isn't clear what your problem is and how we can help you. Are you looking for answers to specific questions like "why does this work the way it does?", or are you worried that you are asking too many questions and it is making you unhappy? We can help with answers to problems of the first kind here, but might not be able to help you with the second one.

Comment: Welcome to stackexhange. Asking "why" is really important in mathematics, even if sometimes teachers are impatient when there are too many questions. You can ask one question at a time here. Write it out carefully, telling us just what you are doing and what particular point you don't understand. Make the mathematics pretty with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I strongly agree with Ethan's point. Questioning why things work the way you're told to do them is really important to build an understanding of the subject. Don't be discouraged from asking such questions.

Comment: I am working about asking many questions and that sometimes my brain dosent get the proof or why it works because sometime i go beyond a algebric maths proof and start finding looking for a more logic proof

Comment: Why this a problem and what answer to this problem do you want?  Do you not actually believe that substitution works and you don't have faith that the answers are legitimate?  Or is it more that you want to understand *everything* and figure if you can't build the universe form logical principals atom by atom then you can't accept you know anything? If the first: substitution works because things that are the same are the same things. If the latter accept that it a very difficult question and that is the basis of *what* advanced theoretical math is, and we spend careers learning. That is good.

Comment: I have completly faith that the answers are legitmates

Comment: "sometimes my brain dosent get the proof"  That is bad.  We need a specific example to help you.  "sometime i go beyond a algebric maths proof and start finding looking for a more logic proof"  That is good. That is abstract math but that is subtle and requires many courses you have years to take.

Comment: the problem is that the teacher dosen't care about proving anything and she says it works because it works and I start getting online to find a prood and think abour something day and night to know why it does work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing about this that seems real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paradoxical thing is the basic and fundamental things are the hardest and we must learn them *last* and dedicate our lives to figuring them out.  But if we learned them first we are doomed to never know anything.

Consider this analogy.  If a child is hungry and asks what to do, you tell it to eat something.  Why does this work?  Why does eating satisfy hunger?  Why does hunger *need* satisfying?  Why does being hungry make us unhappy and why do we wish to avoid being unhappy?  And what does eating have to do with it?

Well, ingesting and digesting food is a chemical process.  There are molecular chains in foods called proteins and... I dont know.  I *never*  learned this stuff.  I don't know *ANYTHING* about what I'm talking about.  I don't know why eating food stops us from being hungry and keeps us alive.  I don't know why staying alive is supposed to be a good thing or why I *want* to stay alive.  None of this do I know.

But some people know and care very much and studied this.  But they didn't study this when it *first* came up when they were two years old and feeling the pangs of hunger.  At that time their parent said "You are hungry because you need food.  Eat food and you won't be hungry".  They didn't counter by saying "But I *can't* eat food unless I know *why* I need to eat food".  If they worried about this they thought "I really want to know why" and when the got a chance they took high school biology and loved it and when they got to university they majored in biology because they really wanted to know the fundamentals.

The rest of us when asked "Why do we eat food when we are hungry" answer "What? Am I a biologist?  'Hungry' means you need food".  And most of us when asked why does $\frac ab c = \frac {ac}b$ say "What? Am I a mathematician?  Multiplication and division distribute.  That's what they are."  ... Unless we *are* mathematicians....

Point being:  Fundamentals are hard.  We spend years trying to properly describe them and figure them out.

Why does $\frac ab\times c = \frac {a\times c}b$.  Well, that depends on our definitions and assumptions.

What is a number and what is multiplication and what is addition.  Well, in the "real world" mass and volume is conserved so when you move amounts together and combine them or separate them into piles the amounts will consistently stay the same no matter what order we do them in.

Why?  What am I?  A physicist?  I don't know.  That's conservation of mass and the universe seems to like it... except in those weird quantum physics and ... why is there anything at all at all instead of nothing... and ... oh heck with it!  I *don't* know.  (There I said it!)  That's how it is.

But I *am* a mathematician.  The question *I* want to know is how can I describe these and break them into consistant logical definitions and properties.

Well, I define something as a "field".  A field is a system of elements with properties.  There are two "binary operations".  A binary operation is a rule that if you take any two elements and you can combine them and you will always get an element in the system.  If you combine the same two elements you will always get the same element and you can combine any two elements and you will always get an element.

Throwing rocks in a pile is a system that works like this.  If our elements are the quantity of rocks and our "binary operation" is tossing one quantity of rocks together with a quantity of rocks, combined they get a quantity of rocks.

So we philosophize and observe and *define* that field is.

A collection of elements.

Two operations called "+" and "$\times$" even though we don't need to specify what those mean.  They will mean different things in *different* systems. so that.

1)  Addition and multiplication is commutative.  It doesn't matter what order we do things in.

2)  Addition and multiplication are associative.  It doesn't matter how we group things as we decide what order we do things in.

3) Addition distributes over multiplication.  That is if $a,b,c$ are three elements $a\times (b+c)$ will result in the same element that $a\times b + a\times c$.

Numerical quantities of rocks obey these rules because there's something funny in the way God made the universe.  But, we mathematicians, with our brains were able to boil this down to the powerful three useful rules above which will serve our needs.

More rules.

4) For addition and multiplication: There is an element so that adding them to an element, or multiplying an elment by them the result is the element.  In other words there is a "neutral" or "identity" element.  For addition this number is "$0$" and $0 + a = a$.  It is a rule that such an element exists.  For multiplication this number is "$1$" and $1 \times a = a$.

5) For any element there is a number that "undoes" it so that can get back to the identity.  This is called an "inverse".  The additive inverse is such that if we have $a$ then there is some element $a'$ so that $a + a' = 0$.  We notate this as $-a$ so that by definition $-a$ is the element so that $a+(-a) = 0$.  For multiplication we notate this either as $\frac 1a$ or as $a^{-1}$.  By definition $\frac 1a$ is the element so that $a \times \frac 1a = 1$.

But there is one catch.  For every $a$ *EXCEPT* $0$ there is a $\frac 1a$ so that $a\times \frac 1a = 1$, but there is no such number for $0$.  This would give an inconsistent result and our system would fail.

(Let $k = a\times 0$ then $0 = k + (-k)$.  $k = a\times 0= a\times (0 + 0) = a\times 0 + a\times 0 = k + k$  So $0 = k + (-k) = k + k + (-k) = k + (k+(-k)) = k + 0 = k$ os $k = a\times 0 = 0$.   So if $\frac 10$ exist we'd have $0 = 0 \times \frac 10 = 1$ so $0=1$.  Which would mean $a = a\times 1 = a\times 0 = 0$ so we only have one element.  The element $0$.  This is actually consistant but not useful.  So if we want a "field" with more than one element we have a rule:)

6) $0 \ne 1$ and there is no $\frac 10$ so that $0\times \frac 10 = 1$.

====

Given all this.

Because multiplication is a binary operation we know that for any $b$ and any $a\ne 0$ that an element $a \times \frac 1b = \frac 1b \times a$ exists.  We can notate this element as $\frac ab$.

So the statement $\frac ab \times c = \frac {ac}b$ means:

The number $(a\times k)\times c$ where $k$ is the number so that $b\times k = 1$ is equal to $a\times (k \times c)$ (because of associativity) which is equal to $a\times (c \times k)$ (by commutativity) = (a\times c)\times k$ (associativity again) = \frac {ac}b$ (just notation).

.....

In other words.  Questioning is good.  But the answer is that we have to lay *fundamental* groundwork and axioms and *identify* precisely what they are first.

Comment: thanks youuuuu that really helped me understand things so muchhhh

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this far past grade 9, I would find myself trying to reprove basic basic facts in exams, because I forgot what the fact was or why it was true.  Part of the problem is that in grade 9, you are not yet mature in recognizing the difference between what is definitional and what is a result.  Another part of the issue is that you have not had enough time to internalize the basic facts so that they are second nature.  The final part of the issue, is you are not yet comfortable knowing to what level of detail a concept deserves to be known at.

My answer is you should keep asking those questions to yourself, and try answering them.  You will find the answers either in the moment, or they will become more natural as you mature mathematically.

For example, the fact $c\cdot \frac{a}{b} = \frac{ca}{b}$ is just a definition, or notation in grade 9.  If you wanted a proof, you would cut a circular pizza into $b$ slices, take $a$ of them, then take $c$ of those.  You can convince yourself that $c\cdot \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b} + ... + \frac{a}{b}= \frac{ca}{b}$

Substitution is the idea that "for 2 equations to be satisfied at the same time, the unknowns must satisfy both equations at the same time".  So you look for a relationship between the unknowns using eq(1), and you know that relationship must hold for eq(2) since the equations are satisfied for the same unknowns. Eventually you get some result like $x=5$, and work backwards through all the relations you found on the way.

Comment: thanks you so much many people say Im smart but I dont think I am, is it a good think to keep asking the question why? because the teacher dosent answer this question or she says because its like that and other students dosent care about why anything works

Comment: There are 2 aspects to look at: what you need to do, and what you want to do.  What you need to do is get good grades, and for that you do't need to keep asking why.  But if you want to try and understand things deeply, you should always ask why.  Most of the time you may not get an answer, or you may get an answer you don't understand.  But after years of asking why and thinking deeply about these things, you will look back and realize how much you learned because of your constant pursuit of the answer to "why"

Comment: People think you are smart because of your results.  You don't because there is so much more you don't know.  So the conclusion is there is no such thing as smart, just curiosity, hard work, and time

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{a}{b}\cdot c=\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{1}=\frac{ac}{b\cdot 1}=\frac{ac}{b}$$

Comment: then why a/b *x/1= ac/b*1?

Comment: This is a law for multiplication of fractions

Comment: but does it have a proof?

Comment: The proof depends an ones definitions and axioms.  I'll write an answer but Id say it works "in the real world" by conservation of volume and mass.  (And why does the real world have conservation of volume and mass? I have no idea. If i cared I'd dedicate my life to studying quantum physics. Which is fine. These questions arent *supposed* to be easy.) The real question to me (which is probably why I'm a theoretical mathematician rather than a theoretical physicist) is here we generalize these to mathematical principals and laws.  I'll go into detail in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics it's important to distinguish between axioms and theorems. Axioms do not require a proof as we accept them as obvious facts. In case $\frac{a}{b}\cdot c$ we can use multiplication commutative law (which says that $x \cdot y=y \cdot x$) so $\frac{a}{b}\cdot c=c \cdot \frac{a}{b}$ and associative law: $c \cdot (a : b)=(c \cdot a) : b$

Both laws were considered as axioms for a long time  until people like you started questioning them and came up with the proofs.
You can refer to this question if you want to know more  [On the commutative property of multiplication (domain of integers, possibly reals)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111603/on-the-commutative-property-of-multiplication-domain-of-integers-possibly-real)

Answer (score 0):

What you mention were mostly axioms, in that they are inherently self explanatory and thus does not require an extensive proof, unlike many of the theorems you see online and back in your 8th grade geometry.

I also went through that time questionong how stiff in math worled, leading me to being a better math student than I was before.

For one of your questions, the substitution property works via the rules of equality, nost of which are simple established axioms, in the sense that they need not any extensive proof to prove their logixal sense.

As you go higher in the realm of higher maths, you will begin to see even more strange results (see the recent 3b1b vid on colliding blocks) and studying the problem and the results can help find the underlying workings that makes the maths possible.

Have a great day!

Comment: so you think I should keep asking myself these queation just think about it one time ans accept that it work?

Comment: Try to look at several proofs for theorems, and there are also branches of math that deals with how axioms work. Such as ZFC or the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering I will tell you how I see for now why substitution (wich sometime is not convincing for me and I start looking for more details) so is this convincing: Consider the system: ax+by=c (1) a'x+b'x=c' (2) For x to be a solution of equation (1) it has to respect the relation x=(c-by)/a we substitute this value of x into the second equation for it to to be solution of both equation, we find y and then we find is this enough proof or I have to think deeper?
Also another question should I think in maths,
because we have a we have b,
or do a to have b
like in substituion we get in a an equation a relation for x( to be solution of that equation or because it is solution to that equation) and should I think we replace the second equation by this relation ( to have the both equation have the same couple solution or because they have the same couple soulution (y=y,x=x) I am allowed to replace)
Another example to make it clearer:
Consider the following situation as an example clearer: Finding 3 numbers (lets call them a , b and c proportional respectivly to 2,5 and 6 and 3a+4b-2c=20 a,b,c prop. to 2 , 5 and 6 gives a/2=b/5=c/6=k which gives a=2k, b=5k ,6k then we replace them.... And here is the question should I think in my head that I replace a by 2k and b by 5k... for them TO BE prop to 2,5... or I am allowed to do that BECAUSE they are proportional to 2,5...?

Comment: The second question is too unclear to understand.  For your first question, it is indeed as simple as find $y$ then find $x$.  You can also think of what is happening when doing that substitution; you are finding the intersection point between 2 lines

Comment: I will try to make it clearer

Comment: Consider the following situation as an example clearer: Finding 3 numbers (lets call them a , b and c proportional respectivly to 2,5 and 6 and 3a+4b-2c=20 a,b,c prop. to 2 , 5 and 6 gives a/2=b/5=c/6=k which gives a=2k, b=5k ,6k then we replace them.... And here is the question should I think in my head that I replace a by 2k and b by 5k... for them TO BE prop to 2,5... or I am allowed to do that BECAUSE they are poportional